# HTTP get request using Arduino Uno and ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, http

I have an Arduino Uno and an ESP8266 and I want to send a HTTP get request to `google.com` and print the response.
Please help me thanks.

Comment: if you have AT firmware in esp8266, use AT commands or WiFiEsp library. the library has examples. for AT commands you can google may examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ESP8266Wifi](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi) Arduino Library.

[Here](https://techtutorialsx.com/2016/07/17/esp8266-http-get-requests/) an example:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password = "yourNetworkPassword";

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("Connecting..");

  }

}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status

    HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient

    http.begin("http://www.google.com");  //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.GET();     //Send the request                                                           

    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code

      String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(payload);                     //Print the response payload

    }

    http.end();   //Close connection

  }

  delay(30000);    //Send a request every 30 seconds

}
```

Comment: but this is for coding directly on esp8266 I want to upload the code to arduino uno

Comment: Ok, do you want to use AT commands? See this post: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32567/get-data-from-website-with-esp8266-using-at-commands